# Integrate $\int{(2x+1)\sqrt{2x-1}}\,dx$ with manipulation

Tags: calculus, integration

I need your help with
$$\int{(2x+1)\sqrt{2x-1}}\,dx$$

The problem is the answer options are all manipulated.

In the options, they combine $\frac{2}{189}(6-3x)^{7/2}$, $\frac{8}{45}(6-3x)^{5/2}$, and $\frac{4}{3}(6-3x)^{3/2}$.

As far, I've substituted the required variables until become $dx$ in the integrand).
\begin{align}
\int{u}\,dv &=-\frac{2}{9}(2x+2)(6-3x)^{3/2}-\int{-\frac{4}{9}(6-3x)^{3/2}}\,dx\\
&=-\frac{2}{9}(2x+2)(6-3x)^{3/2}-\frac{8}{135}(6-3x)^{5/2}\\
\end{align}

Now how to make my answer use the combinations?

**EDIT** The options are below

A. $\frac{2}{189}(6-3x)^{7/2}+\frac{8}{45}(6-3x)^{5/2}-\frac{4}{3}(6-3x)^{3/2}+C$

B. $-\frac{2}{189}(6-3x)^{7/2}-\frac{8}{45}(6-3x)^{5/2}-\frac{4}{3}(6-3x)^{3/2}+C$

C. $-\frac{2}{189}(6-3x)^{7/2}+\frac{8}{45}(6-3x)^{5/2}-\frac{4}{3}(6-3x)^{3/2}+C$

D. $\frac{2}{189}(6-3x)^{7/2}-\frac{8}{45}(6-3x)^{5/2}-\frac{4}{3}(6-3x)^{3/2}+C$

E. $\frac{2}{189}(6-3x)^{7/2}+\frac{8}{45}(6-3x)^{5/2}+\frac{4}{3}(6-3x)^{3/2}+C$

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean for manipulation. You can solve it in a standard manner or you have to use somehow those 3 expressions?

Comment: @AlessioRanallo I've edited the question to make my point clear.

Comment: None of those options are the right one. There is no need for a term to the power of $\frac{7}{2}$. Have you typed the question correctly?

Comment: @IanMiller Yes. I've double-checked it and the options are like them. I also don't get it why there's $\frac{7}{2}$ in the options.

Comment: Integrating each of the options gives the following: $$\sqrt{6-3x}(x^2+8x-6)$$ $$\sqrt{6-3x}(x^2-8x+18)$$ $$\sqrt{6-3x}(x^2+2)$$ $$\sqrt{6-3x}(-x^2+10)$$ $$\sqrt{6-3x}(-x^2+8x-18)$$ None of these match your original question.

Comment: If this is from a textbook it is one of those times where there is an error. Possibly the question got changed but the answer wasn't updated. Maybe a question got deleted or added and the corresponding change to the answers didn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int (2x+1)\sqrt{2x-1} dx\\
=\int (2x-1)\sqrt{2x-1} dx + \int 2\sqrt{2x-1} dx \\
=\int (2x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}} dx + \int 2\sqrt{2x-1} dx \\
=\frac{1}{5}(2x-1)^{\frac{5}{2}}+\frac{2}{3}(2x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}
$$

Comment: I am sure that this was the manipulation the OP was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear to me. In case you are asking about how to solve the integral, consider this hint:

$$(2x+1)(2x-1)^{0.5}=(2x-1+2)(2x-1)^{0.5}=(2x-1)^{1.5}+2 (2x-1)^{0.5} $$

Comment: I've solved the integral but the problem is the answer is still doesn't exist because the options are contain the combination, not the usual result.

Answer (score 0):

Being lazy, I'm going to assume that your work is correct.  Then here's how to simplify your expression.

$$-\frac{2}{9}(2x+2)(6-3x)^{3/2}-\frac{8}{135}(6-3x)^{5/2}= (6-3x)^{3/2}\left[-\frac{2}{9}(2x+2)-\frac{8}{135}(6-3x)\right] \\ = (6-3x)^{3/2}\left[-\frac{4}{9}x-\frac 49-\frac{48}{135}+\frac{8}{45}x\right]
\\ = -\frac{4}{15}(6-3x)^{3/2}(x+3) \\ = \color{red}{\frac 43(6-3x)^{3/2}}\left[-\frac15(x+3)\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

Say $2x-1=z^2$

Then $2dx=2zdz \Rightarrow dx=zdz$

Hence $$I=\int (z^2+2)z \cdot zdz$$
$$=\int (z^4+2z^2)dz=\frac{z^5}{5}+\frac{2z^3}{3}+c$$
$$=\frac{(2x-1)^\frac{5}{2}}{5}+\frac{2(2x-1)^\frac{3}{2}}{3}+c$$